# Ionic route from template html, to other page

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router

I want to make a button in a partial view `tab-suggestion`, that directs to a other view called `tab-profile`. The problem is that `href="#/tab/profile"` doesn't do anything. The links in the tabs nav work just fine, but the button in the ion-view `tab-suggestion` doesn't.

How can I make the button work to direct to `profile`? This is my code:

```
//app.js
.state('tab', {
    url: '/tab',
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: 'templates/tabs.html'
  })

  .state('tab.suggestion', {
    url: '/suggestion',
    views: {
      'tab-suggestion': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/tab-suggestion.html',
        controller: 'SuggestionCtrl'
      }
    }
  })

.state('tab.profile', {
    url: '/profile',
    views: {
      'tab-profile': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/tab-profile.html',
        controller: 'ProfileCtrl'
      }
    }
  })

//index.html
<ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>

//tab-suggestion
<a class="button" ng-if="randomConnection === 'maker'" href="#/tab/profile">Contact</a>
```

**Edit:**
    //tabs.html

```
  <!-- Dashboard Tab -->
  <ion-tab title="Home" icon-off="ion-home" icon-on="ion-home" href="#/tab/home">
    <ion-nav-view name="tab-home"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>
  <ion-tab title="Suggestie" icon-off="ion-android-bulb" icon-on="ion-android-bulb" href="#/tab/suggestion">
    <ion-nav-view name="tab-suggestion"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>
  <ion-tab title="Feed" icon-off="ion-arrow-graph-up-right" icon-on="ion-arrow-graph-up-right" href="#/tab/feed">
    <ion-nav-view name="tab-feed"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>

</ion-tabs>
```

Comment: @Ivaro Yes, my `tabs.html` uses `href`, see my edit.

Comment: Ok, could you remove the `ionic2` tag and add the `ionic` tag? Ill remove my comments to prevent confusion among others

Answer (score 0):

When hitting a tab it's selected by design (as you obviously touch it, Ionic is able to determine that this tab has to be selected now). If you try to route to another tab from a button inside the current view I'd suggest to write a function containing the following content:

```
function() {
    $state.go('yourstate');
    $ionicTabsDelegate.select(0); //index of the tab to select 
}
```

The $ionicTabsDelegate allows you to programmatically select the tab of your choice.

If you need further explanation just let me know, this is the short version due to the fact that I'm typing on a phone. :)